# Apply css style to element when its container/parent element is hovered Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

When I hover over the container of an element I want the element to receive a visual change with css/scss.

requirements:
- Needs to happen from within the child component or sass file. cannot know about parent child relationship.
- sass css or within angular component

I have tried host listener decorator in angular but that is just the host element rather than its parent.

I have tried :host and :host-context selectors but had similar experience to host listener.

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: To visualize this I could  have a small square element inside a large square element, then when the space where small square element does not overlap the area of the large square element is hovered, the small square receives a style.

CLARIFICATION:

[image]

Comment: The child element (the small square in your example) is an Angular component or just and HTML element?

Comment: @ConnorsFan the child element is an angular component.

Comment: For that, using CSS only, you'll need 2 elements inside your _larger square_, one that is filling the larger square, which gets the hover rule, and the smaller square. The main key here is that the small square can't be a child of the one with the hover rule.

Comment: @ConnorsFan The goal is to do this from within the child without knowing anything about the container/parent.

Comment: So to clarify what I meant, for a CSS only solution, it need to be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6egc7f21/

Comment: @LGSon I see what you are getting at and the result is essentially the same. The key I am looking for is that this is all implemented in the child without any knowledge of the parent. I didnt mean to confuse the relationship. It will be parent child and hovering parent (even on top of child) is OK.

Comment: @rjustin But that is exactly what my fiddle does

Comment: So even the mouse over the child should set the style?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes, but I am not as concerned with that. Just that when the parent is hovered anywhere (most importantly the parts where the child does not overlap) then the child receives styling.

Comment: Here is a modified version which might better show what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/6egc7f21/1/ ...and as you can see, none of the hovering is related to the container

Comment: Maybe one of these two stackblitzes does what you want: [stackblitz1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eshoho), [stackblitz2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cw9i53). I did it with event listeners because you want to control everything from the child, and there is no "parent" selector in CSS.

Comment: Another option is, if your _smaller square_ is a child of the container, to use this CSS rule: `*:hover .smaller_square { background: red; }`

Comment: @LGSon Ok I see so what you are getting at, having two elements one which covers the whole parent just to listener for the hover. This is clever but it will conflict with other children which are there but not apart of this process. See image in post(Gold star would be affected although it is not in play for this hover).

Comment: No it won't, as when hover the star nothing will happen with the _small square_. Put it all together and you'll see ... and here is an update of my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6egc7f21/2/

Comment: And yet another sample: http://jsfiddle.net/6egc7f21/3/

Comment: @LGSon Ok yes this is correct although I use a Flexbox layout (which was not mentioned in the post) does this cause issue regarding layout?

Comment: No, can't see how that would change anything. When using absolute positioning on an flex item, it as well is taken out of flow

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes this is a good solution I will likely go with something like this. Not as elegant as one could hope but not as hacky as my other attempts.

Comment: If you prefer one of the two, I could post an answer.

Comment: @LGSon To have the position be absolute in the hovered element it is required that the container be position:relative. This I cannot ensure. I like this as a solution and would upvote if you post as an answer.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Is the hostlistener decorator actually being used? Or is it all happening via event listeners?

Comment: I use the `HostListener` in the case where you would exclude the child component from the "hover zone" (see [the code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cw9i53?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)). I use event listeners to handle the events on the parent.

Comment: @ConnorsFan ah i see, either is a fine solution. maybe post the one with the exclusion of child so others can have it but remove it if they dont want it.

Comment: Then you should take a look at what _danday_ suggest, which I also did in a comment, but I used the global selector `*` and a unique class, e.g. `*:hover .smaller_square { background: red; }`. To this you can add the child selector `>` if needed, if to narrow it down further.

Comment: I will wait to see if you can make it work with the CSS solution proposed by danday74 and LGSon.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML of the small square, wrap it with a div:

```
<div class="small-square">
  // rest of HTML
</div>
```

In the CSS of small square:

```
.small-square:hover {
  // styles
}
```

Why can't you do this? Sorry if I don't fully understand the question.

UPDATE:

You could do this in your global stylesheet (AKA styles.css):

```
.large-square:hover .small-square {
  // styles for small square when large square is hovered
}
```

UPDATE 2:

Not sure if host context would support use of :hover as follows:

```
:host-context(.large-square:hover) .small-square {
  // styles for small square when large square is hovered
}

:host-context(*:hover) .small-square {
  // styles for small square when large square is hovered
}
```

If it doesn't then I think you have no choice but to use global stylesheet.

Comment: I appreciate the response! The 'small square' can go into many containing elements. The size will not be known. The child or 'small square' should not know about its container. yet when the container is hovered the child should receive a style.

Comment: (1) regardless of its containing element, it should still change color when hovered? (2) I can't see relevance of size (3) when the parent container is hovered the child should receive the style? or when child is hovered the child should receive the style?

Comment: when parent element is hovered child should receive style. This cant be implemented in the parent. See image I added to post, thanks!

Comment: I would like to avoid global styling. implementation should be within child.

Comment: Also small square could be added dynamically and a large square class may not be able to be applied.

Comment: there must be some CSS selector that would always pinpoint a large square even if it is not a class, alternatively can't you just wrap a large square in a large square class?

Comment: As I commented above, use the global selector, e.g. `*:hover .smaller_square {background: red;}` ...and maybe in combo with the child selector `>`

Comment: @LGSon This is also a good option, I would have to test that it works within a component css class given the shadow dom emulation but in theory this should work.